# Multiple DisplayMember using special class

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I am trying to get a ListBox to display a concatenation of multiple rows of table `Accommodation`.

Because I can't edit the datasource, I prepared a class, `AccommodationEntity`, which contains both the original `Accommodation` object and the string I want the ListBox to display.

However, for some reason, I fail to set the DisplayMember property of the ListBox, which thus displays the default jibber-jabber.

I set up the listbox as follows:

```
accommodationList.DisplayMember = "textToShow";
// load and set up accommodation
List<AccommodationEntity> relatedAccommodations = 
    dt.listHolidayAccommodation(relatedHoliday);
accommodationList.DataSource = relatedAccommodations;
accommodationList.Refresh();
```

The class for the objects stored in the datasource looks like this:

```
class AccommodationEntity
{
    public accommodation classicAccommodation;
    public string textToShow;

    public AccommodationEntity(stay relatedStay)
    {
        this.classicAccommodation = relatedStay.accommodation;

        string from = relatedStay.dateFrom.ToString();
        string to = relatedStay.dateTo.ToString();
        string city = relatedStay.accommodation.location.ToString();
        string hotelName = relatedStay.accommodation.name.ToString();

        this.textToShow = hotelName + ", " + city + " (" + from + " - " + to + ")";
    }
}
```

}
`

And finally, there is a method which does some searching (returning correct objects):

```
public List<AccommodationEntity> listHolidayAccommodation(holiday selectedHoliday)
{
    List<AccommodationEntity> ubytovani = new List<AccommodationEntity>();

    var stays = from singleStay in selectedHoliday.stays
                select singleStay;

    foreach (stay singleStay in stays)
    {
        AccommodationEntity newStay = new AccommodationEntity(singleStay);
        ubytovani.Add(newStay);
    }

    return ubytovani;
}
```

I know the dataSource contains the right data, but for some reason, it seems the DisplayMember property remains set to `""`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to set the DisplayMember and DisplayValue like this. Where "Name"/"Value" is the name of the property in the Accomodation class.

```
List<AccommodationEntity> relatedAccommodations = dt.listHolidayAccommodation(relatedHoliday);
accommodationList.DataSource = relatedAccommodations;
accommodationList.DisplayMember = "Name";
accommodationList.ValueMember = "Value";
```

**UPDATE:**

Make sure `textToShow` is actually a Property, not just a public field.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I do that when the form initializes by using

accommodationList.DisplayMember = "textToShow";

where textToShow is the name of the property containing the string I want to display

Comment: @Ondrej: If you are setting the properties as you are supposed to, perhaps post some of the code for the other relevant classes. Maybe something is not being set correctly for them.

Comment: @Ondrej: Make sure textToShow is a Property. public string TextToShow { get { //return value } }. Set that property as the DisplayMember

Comment: Thank you! Getter was what I was missing

Comment: Good catch @RBDev. You'd think I would have noticed that after reformatting the code in the question ;) +1.

Answer (score 4):

Are you setting the [DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) properties? Have a look at the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx) property on MSDN to see how they are setting all three properties.

**UPDATE:**

Try switching this:

```
accommodationList.DisplayMember = "textToShow";
// load and set up accommodation
List<AccommodationEntity> relatedAccommodations = 
    dt.listHolidayAccommodation(relatedHoliday);
accommodationList.DataSource = relatedAccommodations;
```

to this:

```
// load and set up accommodation
List<AccommodationEntity> relatedAccommodations = 
    dt.listHolidayAccommodation(relatedHoliday);
accommodationList.DataSource = relatedAccommodations;
accommodationList.DisplayMember = "textToShow";
```

Comment: see my last comment, I do, but it still displays the default value

Comment: @Ondrej: What happens if you set the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties after you bind the list to the `DataSource`. So don't do it in the form intitializer, but do it right after the line `accomodationList.Datasource = relatedAccomodations;`

Comment: if I set up DisplayMember like you suggest, nothing changes, if I set ValueMember as well, I get the following error: 

Cannot bind to the new display member.
Parameter name: newDisplayMember